# Limit of a Binomial Weighted Sum of Exponential Terms...

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, limits, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to solve for the limit of a binomial weighted sum as n goes to infinity. It is given as:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\exp(\frac{b(\frac{n}{2}-k)^2}{n}})$$

The limit is convergent for the parameter b<2, and I can show in Mathematica plots for large n that it is (approximately)
$$
\sqrt{\frac{2}{2-b}}
$$

but of course I would like to derive it. I think it is related to the continous Normal case,
$$
\sqrt{\frac{a}{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp(\frac{b x^2}{2}-\frac{a x^2}{2})\,\mathrm dx=\sqrt{\frac{a}{a-b}}
$$

for a>b. Any hints how to derive the limit for the binomial case are very much welcome.

Comment: You can get proper formatting for operators like $\lim$ and $\exp$ using `\lim` and `\exp`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: Ok, I did. Thank you!

Comment: @Nafets I edited your post. Please check for correctness.

Comment: Yes, it is correct as edited. Thank you very much Aaron!

Comment: What is $b$ here?

Comment: A parameter, for my applied purpose also b>0 can be assumed.